# How to duplicate data from application level? Not database level

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am stuck for duplicate data from my application.

Let's say I have:

```
PetBooks Table:
id
book_name


Pet:
id
book_id
code
name
type

Petbooks
1 MyPet

Pet:
1 1 CAT1 Josh Cat
2 1 CAT2 Ron Cat
3 1 DOG1 Max Dog
```

Question 1:
How can I duplicate Petbook and all its pets?

So After I duplicate the petbook, it should look like

```
Petbooks
1 MyPet
2 MyPet(Copy)


Pet:
1 1 CAT1 Josh Cat
2 1 CAT2 Ron Cat
3 1 DOG1 Max Dog
4 2 CAT1 Josh Cat
5 2 CAT2 Ron Cat
6 2 DOG1 Max Dog
```

The solution I think is, to get all of the pet where book_id = 1, then looping and insert one by one, but it's so slow especially when there are a lot of data.

Comment: Fetch all data from DB and then insert it to DB (though I'm not sure why you would want to do this from your application). Also, copying & pasting all data will indeed take a while if there is a lot of data.

Comment: @DavidLee Thank you for comment. Yes what I think is fetch all data and insert it one by one, But the problem is when the data grow, it will overflow the memory when fetch all data. And very slow when insert one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this somewhat painfully -- assuming that ids are assigned automatically and some column other than `id` is unique in the original data.  Let me call that column `name`.

Then:

```
insert into petbooks (book_name)
    select concat('Copy of ', book_name)
    from petbooks;
```

Then for `pets`, we have to look up the new id.  We can create a look-up table on the fly using aggregation:

```
insert into pets (book_id, code, name, type)
    select pb.max_id, code, name, type)
    from pets p join
         (select name, min(id) as min_id, max(id) as max_id
          from petbooks
          group by name
         ) pb
         on pb.min_id = p.book_id
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I wonder what if the id is a UUID and should be generated by the application?

Comment: @SusiS . . . That makes it a bit trickier.  You could include a `createdAt` date/time and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle the relationship manually one by one, and combine them to a procedure. You may use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function to get the latest `id`. For example:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_petbook(petbook_id INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PetBooks (book_name)
        SELECT CONCAT(book_name, '(Copy)')
        FROM Petbooks
        WHERE id = petbook_id;
    DECLARE last_insert_id BIGINT;
    SET last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO Pet (book_id, code, name, type)
        SELECT lid.last_insert_id , code, name, type
        FROM Pet JOIN (SELECT last_insert_id) as lid
        WHERE book_id = petbook_id;
END
```

If you want to use UUIDs for the `id` column, you may change the signature to `CHAR(36)` and then use the [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_petbook(petbook_id CHAR(36))
BEGIN
    DECLARE uuid CHAR(36);

    -- Generate an UUID which has not been used.
    REPEAT
        SET uuid = UUID();
    UNTIL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PetBooks WHERE id = uuid) = 0 END REPEAT;

    -- Insert rows with the UUID
    INSERT INTO PetBooks (id, book_name)
        SELECT u.uuid, CONCAT(book_name, '(Copy)')
        FROM Petbooks JOIN (SELECT uuid) as u
        WHERE id = petbook_id;
    INSERT INTO Pet (book_id, code, name, type)
        SELECT u.uuid, code, name, type
        FROM Pet JOIN (SELECT uuid) as u
        WHERE book_id = petbook_id;
END
```

You may generate more UUIDs in the same way if you are also using an UUID for the `id` column in other tables.

Finally, just call the procedure:

```sql
CALL copy_petbook(/* Put the id here. */);
```