# How to merge data from table database in application level not database level?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am stuck to merge data from my application.

Let's say I have:

```
PetBooks Table:
id
book_name


Pet:
id
book_id
code
name
type

Petbooks
1 MyPet
2 MyPet(Copy)


Pet:
1 1 CAT1 Josh Cat
2 1 CAT2 Ron Cat
3 1 DOG1 Max Dog
4 2 CAT1 Josh Cat
5 2 CAT2 Ronnie Cat
6 2 DOG1 Max Dog
```

**Question: I want to merge Book id 1 and book id 2, it's should check the pet code, if the pet code is the same, then it should assume it's the same, but it should check the name, and type. If there is different, then it should use comma (,) to join.**

So the result should look like this:

Merge book id 1 to book id 2:

```
Petbooks
2 MyPet(Copy)


Pet:
4 2 CAT1 Josh Cat
5 2 CAT2 Ronnie,Ron Cat
6 2 DOG1 Max Dog
```

Look at pet id 5, the name is different so it will concat the pet name with a comma

The solution I think is to get all the pet where book_id = 1, and get all the pet where book_id = 2, and check it one by one and insert it one by one, but it's so slow, I think it's n^2, and it's very slow especially when the data grow

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: How do you know which value you have to take in `id` and `book_id`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN We will use the destination id, and destination book_id, It's merge from book_id 1 to book_id 2, so we will use book_id 2

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2cdb505f276924422388756816149630

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to duplicate data from application level? Not database level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171549/how-to-duplicate-data-from-application-level-not-database-level)

Comment: @philipxy No, your link is about how to duplicate the data (it's like a new branch in git). And my question here is about how to merge the duplicate data(it's like merge in git). That's a different thing